# ERROR: The SaveAs method is configured to require a rooted path, and the path '~/Documents/Upload/Abc.mdb' is not rooted

Tags: c#, asp.net

I m Trying to upload a mdb file in my database so my code is

```
if (fileUploadEspace.HasFile)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string savePath = string.Empty;
                        savePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UploadDBFilePath"];
                        Server.ScriptTimeout = 100000000;


                        fileUploadEspace.SaveAs(savePath + fileUploadEspace.FileName);
```

in web.config file i kept the path as

```
 <add key="UploadDBFilePath" value="~/Documents/Upload/" />
```

but when I m clicking Upload buttton it is giving me above error message. I searched for the same error but still the error in not resolving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`SaveAs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.saveas(v=vs.110).aspx) needs a physical path for writing  the file, you will have to use [`Server.MapPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632(v=vs.90).aspx) for generating  it.

For  creating path by combining the file name and the path use [`Path.Combine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine(v=vs.110).aspx) and then on that call `Server.MapPath` to get the Physical path and then `SaveAs` can write the file in that directory.

```
fileUploadEspace.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(Path.Combine(savePath,fileUploadEspace.FileName)));
```